# Python dataframe transpose where some rows have multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe:

```
field,value
a,1  
a,2  
b,8
```

I want to pivot it to this form

```
a,b  
1,8  
2,8
```

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `set_index` with a `cumcount` on each `field` group + `field`
- `unstack` + `ffill`

---

```
df.set_index(
    [df.groupby('field').cumcount(), 'field']
).value.unstack().ffill().astype(df.value.dtype)

field  a  b
0      1  8
1      2  8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like so:

```
# df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
df.pivot(columns=field, values=value).bfill().dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print (df)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  8
```

Solution with creating groups for new index by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and fill forward missing values:

```
g = df.groupby(0).cumcount()
df1 = pd.pivot(index=g, columns=df[0], values=df[1]).ffill().astype(int)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  8
```

Another solution creates groups with `apply` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[1].values)).unstack(0).ffill().astype(int)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  8
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would just be to do `DataFrame.T` (transpose)

```
df_new = df.T
```